# pushing icons closer together in footer gone wrong?

Tags: css

im trying to create a footer with a few social media icons...however, the method i've tried has resulted in the following problem :
expectation:

[image]

reality:

[image]

as you can see i'm failing in bringing the social media icons closer together... i tried setting the columns flex % to - however that pulls everything closer together towards the left of the screen...

here is my .row and .column as well as the social media icons..

```
    .row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 30%;
  padding: 00px;

}

.marginauto1 {
 margin: 30px auto 20px;
display: block;
horizontal-align; middle;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

```
<footer class= "marginauto1">
<center><div class="row">
  <div class="column">
<center><a class= "pointer" href="twitter_url">
```

first time taking a stab at this on my own and I'm just really stuck here.. any help or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried 
'justify-content: center;'  among the 'display: flex'

Comment: Your HTML and CSS both have syntax errors. Please give a MWE (minimal working example).

Answer (score 0):

Its working as expected. You have defined `.column` with `flex: 30%;` which intrun will split into 3

- flex-grow: 1;
- flex-shrink: 1;
- flex-basis: 30%;

So what have you done is allowing the element to grow till the available width with a minimum of `30%` relative to the container. This is because the `flex-basis` is defined. This will be `33%` each.

For your soution to work remove `flex: 30%;` from `.column`. This will take the width depending on the content.

If you want some gap between the element, try adding some `margin` or `padding`, I have used margin for that. Or you can set the width of `column` element.

Inorder to align the items center in horizontal axis, use `justify-content: center;` for the `flex` element.

**Working Fiddle**

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.marginauto1 {
  margin: 30px auto 20px;
  display: block;
}

.pointer img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="marginauto1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="pointer" href="">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-512.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="pointer" href="">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-512.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="pointer" href="">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-512.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Your content are not being aligned to the center :(

Comment: @Uttam In order to align the items center in horizontal axis, use justify-content: center; for the flex element. I didnt added that since that was not specified in the question. Updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all your icons together in the middle:

```css
img{
  height:50px;
}

div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyFcxKQYRAhR9esHvHVZokZGCYFNC1_rMHhw&usqp=CAU">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<center>` tag will not applicable if you are using flexbox. Instead flex-box itself has some properties that you can make use of. In your use-case you can go with `justify-content: center`

```css
.row{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .item{
      color: red;
      background: lightblue;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<footer class= "marginauto1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item 1">
          <h1>Telegram</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item 2">
          <h1>Facebook</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item 3">
          <h1>Twitter</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

If you don't want any space in between of 2 or more items you can remove the margin.